# new view controller in rviz (fixed to the center of the target frame): how to rotate with the frame?

Tags: rviz, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a new view controller for rviz. Heavily based on FPS, but cannot be translated, so that it stays attached to the target frame (I copied from FPS and suppressed the code related to translation).

I attach it to a frame inside the car (think base_link + offset), so that it gives a view from the drivers perspective.

But when the car turns, the camera does not turn with the car. I want it to be always aligned with the target frame, plus whatever yaw and pitch I give it with the mouse.

How to achieve that please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74563/new-view-controller-in-rviz-(fixed-to-the-center-of-the-target-frame):-how-to-rotate-with-the-frame?/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2013-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-08-23**:
cool. Sadly I'm still using Fuerte... I'm planning to upgrade in a couple of months, I'll use your plugin then. Meanwhile I see if I can do some backport...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently wrote a view controller which does exactly that. It's part of the oculus plugin: https://github.com/ros-visualization/oculus_rviz_plugins/blob/groovy-devel/src/fixed_view_controller.cpp

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1